# Binding from context menu item to parent control

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a control, on that control is a command called SaveToClipboardCommand. I want to bind a context menu item command to that command so that when i click it, the copy to clipboard command is executed.

```
<Control x:Name="Control">
    <Control.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command={"Bind to SaveToClipboardCommand here"} Header="Some Header" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Control.ContextMenu/>
</Control>
```

The control (for argument sake) is defined like this:

```
partial class Control
{
      private ICommand _saveToClipboard;
      public ICommand SaveToClipboardCommand
      {
          get
          {
              if (_saveToClipboard == null)
              {
                  _saveToClipboard = new RelayCommand(
                         x=> SaveToClipboard());
              }
              return _saveToClipboard;
          }
     }
}
```

I have tried using RelativeSource and ElementName based bindings but both are failing. Is what i am trying to do even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What RelativeSource have you tried?  Did you try FindAncestor?

Comment: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}, Path-SaveToClipboardCommand}`

Comment: Are you trying to bind to a control's context menu to a command defined within the control? If so then you should do the binding in that control's XAML and set its DataContext to 'this'. If you are binding to the command member outside the scope of 'Control' class then the DataContext should have it so that it is resolved.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**EDIT** (after showing how the control is exposed):
Well ContextMenu is somewhat tricky, because it's actually not part of the same visual tree. Try doing this:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.SaveToClipboardCommand,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
```

**Original answer**

> Is this command exposed as a public
>   property of the Control? If the
>   command is actually exposed in a
>   ViewModel hanging of the control's
>   DataContext, to do the following:
>
> ```
> Command={Binding ElementName=Control, Path=DataContext.SaveToClipboardCommand}
> ```
>
> Can you show how this command is
>   currently exposed?

Comment: Command is in edit. RelayCommand is just a standard ICommand implementation

Comment: Well ContextMenu is somewhat tricky, because it's actually not part of the same visual tree. Try doing this:
   <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.SaveToClipboardCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

Comment: i'll have a look into this tomorow :) thanks mate. Bloody context menus

Comment: Excellent! it worked. I will have to look more into the placement target binding :) thanks for your assistance

Answer (score -3):

```
Command={Binding ElementName=Control, Path=SaveToClipboardCommand}
```

HTH

Comment: Tried that, but it isnt working for me :( says 'Binding cannot find source...'