# Binding menu item to command

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to bind a command to a view model but it is not triggering

```
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Lister.WPF.ViewModels"
    DataContext="{Binding ViewModel:TweetViewModel}" Icon="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/internet_down_16_hot.png" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <!--Test-->
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem BorderThickness="5" Header="Status">
                <MenuItem BorderThickness="5" Header="Timeline" Command="{Binding  RefreshTweetsCommand}"/>
```

Here is the code from the VM

```
    private RelayCommand _refreshTweetsCommand;
    public RelayCommand RefreshTweetsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _refreshTweetsCommand ??
                   (_refreshTweetsCommand =
                    new RelayCommand(RefreshTweetList, LoadTweets));
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a popup control, ContextMenu is not in the visual tree -- hence it does not inherit the DataContext.  There are workarounds for this, see here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3910726/1001985

Comment: @McGarnagle this is Menu not ContextMenu, it will have the DataContext of the parent.

Comment: It is not a context menu, the command worked fine

Comment: @nit my bad, sorry. Have to be more careful with that nuclear close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContext="{Binding ViewModel:TweetViewModel}"` This is no way of binding `DataContext`.

Set your DataContext as follows:

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:TweetViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```