# Binding command in context menu

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to learn how to use a contextmenu. I get the menu and it looks good but the commands do not bind in the contextmenu. They do work in the visible button stack panel below the contextmenu. I get this in the output :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MainGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.StartClientCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lbSlaves" Grid.Row="1"  
             ItemsSource="{Binding Slaves}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel  />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="150" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FriendlyName, Mode=OneWay}" >
                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Start" 
                                                  Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.StartClientCommand}" 
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                        <MenuItem Header="Stop" 
                                                  Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.StopClientCommand}" 
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"  />
                                        <MenuItem Header="Calibrate" 
                                                  Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CalibrateClientCommand}" 
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Button 
                        Content="Start"  
                        Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.StartClientCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

                        <Button 
                        Content="Stop"  
                        Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.StopClientCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

                        <Button 
                        Content="Calibrate"  
                        Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CalibrateClientCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thake a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878620/binding-from-context-menu-item-to-parent-control

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tricky. As ContextMenu isn't a part of the visual tree you need to pass the data context in different way. You can do it as followed:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FriendlyName, Mode=OneWay}" Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=MainGrid}" >
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Start" 
                      Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.StartClientCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Stop" 
                      Command="{Binding  Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.StopClientCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"  />
            <MenuItem Header="Calibrate" 
                      Command="{Binding  Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.CalibrateClientCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ContextMenu` is not part of the Visual Tree, so you can't reach your Grid.

You can get the containing control of `ContextMenu` using `PlacementTarget` property.

If you have desgined your `ViewModel` properly, then your `DataContext` would reach your CM. In your case, your `DataTemplate's` `DataContext` would be enough. If that is not you want, and your Commands are present as static members like the way we have in [NavigationCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.navigationcommands(v=vs.100).aspx) class, then you need to assign Command like :

```
<MenuItem Command="{x:Static local:MyCommands.CustomCommand}" ... />
```