# Unable to use FindAncestor to bind to parent properties with a ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, contextmenu

I have a ListBox with a ContextMenu and I am trying to bind to the Tag.
I am able to use RelativeSource/FindAncestor to bind to the `Tag` from the `ItemTemplate` but this same approach doesn't work for the `ContextMenu`.

I looked through the Live Visual Tree in Visual Studio and I see the ListBox Items but I don't see the ContextMenu. What is the proper way to do this binding if the ListBox is not an Ancestor of the ContextMenu in the Visual Tree?

**Note:** I intend to create a ContextMenu in the `Page.Resources` that I can use in more than one ListBox so I do not want to use `ElementName` to bind to specific controls.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
         x:Name="SetupStepsList"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         KeyDown="ListBox_KeyDown"
         Tag="This is the tag"
         Style="{StaticResource GenericListBox}"
         SelectedValue="{Binding ActiveStep, Mode=TwoWay}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TightListBox}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedStation.SetupSteps, Mode=OneWay}">

   <ListBox.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
         <MenuItem Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=Tag}" >
            <MenuItem.Icon>
               <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Plus"
                                           Style="{StaticResource MenuIconStyle}"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
         </MenuItem>
      </ContextMenu>
   </ListBox.ContextMenu>

   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock AllowDrop="False"
                       Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=Tag}"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding from context menu item to parent control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878620/binding-from-context-menu-item-to-parent-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ContextMenu` is not part of the same visual tree as the `ListBox`, therefore `RelativeSource` bindings do not work. You can do this instead:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
```

This works, because the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu` is the parent `ListBox`.